# Retrieve Object From Nested List Spring JpaRepository

Tags: java, nested, spring-data-jpa, repository, jpql

I do have a repository

```
public interface GroupRepository extends JpaRepository<Group, Integer> {
}
```

The **Group** does have a *list* of items

```
private List<Item> items;
```

Each **Item** has a *position* property

```
private int position;
```

> How can I retrieve a **group** *by knowing* the **position** of an item
>   present in one of the *lists*?

### **Item.java**

```
public class Item extends PersistedBean{
 private int position;
 private Group group;

 @Column(name = "Position")
  public int getPosition() {
    return position;
  }

  @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
  @JoinColumn(name = "GroupId", referencedColumnName = "Id")
  public Group getGroup() {
    return group;
  }
}
```

### Group.java

```
public class Group extends PersistedBean {
 private int position;
 private List<Item> items;

  @Column(name = "Position")
  public int getPosition() {
    return position;
  }

  @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "group", orphanRemoval = false)
  public List<Item> getItems() {
    return items;
  }

}
```

Comment: Could you show your entity classes?

Comment: i edited the question

Comment: So position is unique for all the *items*? Otherwise you will retrieve all the groups having any of their items(position = *X*);

Comment: yes, the position is unique for all

Comment: Have you tried *find<All / One>ByItemsPositionIn(int pos);* ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could add query to your `JpaRepository<Group, Integer>` repository, something like should work:

```
@Query("SELECT g FROM Group g " + 
       "JOIN g.items i ON i.position IN :p")
List<Group> getGroupsWhenPositionMatchAnyRelatedItem(@Param("p") Integer p);
```

Comment: This is gr8. I'll mark it as accepted. One more thing. Could here be added a WHERE statement where a Cart could be specified as parameter? Thank you

Comment: Shure you can add where statement, but it is JPQL not SQL, remember.